# Data Report in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, report

i want migrate from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017
in 2010 i'm using Data Report (and called SSRS)
how i use data report in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Step 1: you will install w/e version of VS2017 (community, pro , enterprise) Step 2: you will need to download SSDT ; you can Dl from this url directly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer 
Set up and make sure to click reporting services as that is what you need (SSIS, SSAS if you also need). Once install is done restart. and under BI of new project you should see SSRS report solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the way, i can compile and run VS2010 app with reports, but i can't Design Reports, because editor show me RDLC files as XML structure.
then i install ([Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001))
now i can design report files by easy, and i still can using Data Report as VS2010